# Find the interval(s) where the function is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f(x)=e^{6x}-ln(x-10)$

What is the interval on which the function is continuous?

Comment: Use the properties of logarithmic function to determine the interval.

Comment: e is continuous at all values of x, ln is continuous at all values greater than 0, that should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $e^x$ is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the $ln x$ function is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

Hence, $e^{6x}$ is continuous for every $x \in \mathbb{R} ...(i)$

whereas, $ln(x-10)$ is continuous $\forall (x-10)>0 \implies x>10 \implies x \in (10,\infty) ...(ii)$.

Taking the intersection of these two sets of values of $x$, we infer that

$f(x)=e^{6x}-ln(x-10)$ is continuous $\forall x \in (10,\infty)$.